# Adding folder to app rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How to add folder in to rails app directory. 
in my config/require.rb

```
Dir[File.join(Rails.root, "app/models", "extract_form_objects", "*.rb")].each {|l| require l }
```

but when i start rails project `rails s` i have error:

```
/home/sergey/rubystack_2.0.0-5/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/virtus-0.5.5/lib/virtus/class_methods.rb:67:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant ChannelTemplateEventPost::ActivModel (NameError)
```

this is my class rb file in app/models/extract_form_objects

```
class ChannelTemplateEventPost

  include Virtus
  extend ActivModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_reader :user_posts
  attr_reader :events

  attribute :channel_id, Integer
  attribute :current_user_id, Integer
  attribute :post_id, Array



  def save
    persist!
  end

  private
    def persist!
      @event = Event.creata!(event_post_list: post_id, user_id: current_user_id,urrent_user_id: current_user_id)
    end
end
```

Comment: `e` is missing in `Active` ..may be that is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As the guys already mentioned You have a typo. Plus Rails will expect You to namespace those objects by folder, so it will be:

```
class ExtractFormObjects::ChannelTemplateEventPost
```

Comment: do not work error `/home/sergey/rubystack_2.0.0-5/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/virtus-0.5.5/lib/virtus/class_methods.rb:67:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant ExtractFormObjects::ChannelTemplateEventPost::ActivModel (NameError)
`

Comment: `ActiveModel` not `ActivModel`. You have typos all over the place.

Comment: Сережа, не тупите, вам уже 4 раза указали на опечатку :) ( just told him in Russian to fix the typo, seems like he doesn't understand )